# Reload page at resize event versus hmtl5 video full screen mode

Tags: jquery, html, video, resize, reload

I have the following problem:

On my new webpage (http://test.kosuch.eu/en/stefanie/index.php) I generelly want pages to reload when the window size has been changed. I use a template ruled by Isotope (see isotope.metafizzy.co) and have the following function for the resize event. So far everything works fine!

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        $container_home.isotope('reLayout')
}).trigger("resize");
```

Now I am also using the html5 video tag to post videos, see http://test.kosuch.eu/en/stefanie/dancing/. However, when clicking on the "Full screen" button for the video, the event is regarded as a window resize, i.e., the page reloads and the full screen is immediately closing down again. It's quite logical, I know.

So does anyone has an idea how to handle this?

I had the following 3 ideas and I searched for answers on the net but did not find any answer:
1. Can I turn of the resize trigger just for the page with the videos? (Not optimal, but would be sufficient for the moment.)
2. Can I turn of the resize trigger when changing to video full screen mode?
3. Is there a html5 video tag option that does open the video without a resize event or something similar?

Any help and ideas welcome!

Regards,
Stefanie

Comment: Check inside resize handler using: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/document.mozFullScreen

Comment: Thanks! I added a check for full screen mode in the resize trigger. However, the full screen check checks if the **browser** is in full screen mode. So indeed, if I am in full screen mode with my browser and then start playing the video in full screen mode it works. But generelly users are not working in fullscreen mode. So this is not yet the answer I am looking for (but I might use your idea for a workaround e.g. costumizing the full screen button myself).

Comment: In fact, I noticed that the full screen mode of the video always works when the browser in already in full screen mode. Changing to fullscreen mode from a browser window that is already maximized is not seen as a resize - so I really do not understand the difference between playing a video in full screen mode when the browser window is just maximized (not working) and playing a video in full sreen mode when the browser is in full screen mode itself (working). Any explanations or, even better, solutions that do not involve the user to be obliged to change to the browser's full screen mode? Thx!

Comment: And yet another information: I am generelly testing with Mozilla Firefox 30.0. With Internet Explorer the workaround with going to the browser's full screen before playing the video in full screen does not work, i.e., even in full screen mode a resize event seems to be fired when opening the video in full screen :-(

Comment: I have the same problem have you found a solution? ( in my case videos are from vimeo and youtube ...)

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved the same issue working with the YouTube HTML5 player - the fullscreen functionality utilises the HTML5 fullscreen API and would trigger `window.resize` events.

The solution was to detect fullscreen API activation, and temporarily disable the `window.resize` callback. A little ugly, but it but working and tested in Chrome 37, FF 32, and IE11.

```js
var fullscreen = false;

if (screenfull.enabled) {
    document.addEventListener(screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange, function() {
        // switching to full screen
        if (screenfull.isFullscreen) {
            fullscreen = screenfull.isFullscreen;

        // leaving full screen
        } else {
            // short delay to let browser finish resizing the viewport
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                fullscreen = screenfull.isFullscreen;
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}

var resizeCallback = function() {
    if (fullscreen) return;

    // ... complex layout logic
}
```

[Screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/) smooths out the browser implementation differences of the fullscreen API - recommended.